# How should I map a series of geo traces to the different directions of e.g. a crossroads?

Tags: java, geolocation, mapping

I have a List of geo traces that all contain crossings of a crossroads.
I now have to sort them to the different driving directions e.g. all traces that made a left turn at the crossroads.

How would you tackle this problem. I am not really stuck, but I am searching for some input. I really would like the solution to be independent from map data.

Also I am developing in Java. If you need more specific information just let me know.